# Caching Typekit CSS

Tags: css, fonts, typekit

I'm using [TypeKit](http://typekit.com/fonts) to provide fonts for a site I'm developing.  When the page is loading it loads slow (more than a second).  Turns out that this is because it's downloading the fonts on every requests.  It's beyond me that a service such as this doesn't have etags configured to get clients to cache the fonts...but I digress.  Until TypeKit fixes this I host the CSS locally temporarily.

Anyone had this issue with TypeKit?  How did you work around it?  Perhaps I'm wrong?

Comment: Hmm... that could be part of the business model or down to legal issues. But on every call? Have you looked at the ceche-control headers in the resources they serve out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [**posting on their getsatisfaction.com account**](http://getsatisfaction.com/typekit/topics/use_far_future_expires_headers_for_better_caching), they have at least some caching in place:

> One thing to note is that although the fonts are served with an Expires header, they're also served with an Etag. The browser is required to make a request after 5 minutes, but will normally use the Etag to generate a 304 (Not Modified) response - meaning, the fonts aren't actually downloaded again.

can you check what happens using Firebug?